# "What do" or "what does" when using "and" or "or"?

Tags: questions

Consider the following sentences, where X and Y represent words that the person does not understand:

1. > What do X and Y mean?
2. > What does X and Y mean?
3. > What do X or Y mean?
4. > What does X or Y mean?

From my understanding, (1) and (4) are correct, while (2) and (3) are wrong. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to understand the differences if you apply them to examples. All of them are possible in the right context although some are much more likely than others.

> What do (the words)TIME and TEMPO mean?
> (What do these two words mean?)

> What does (the expression) PICK and PAY refer to?
> (It means choose an item in a shop and pay for it.)

> What do (bow or sow) mean (as the words appear in several different contexts)?
> (Each word means different things - bow of a ship, bow and arrow, bow in one's hair, to bow down / female pig, scatter seed)

> What does (the word) RUSTIC or (the word) TRUSTY mean?
> (One of them should fit in my crossword puzzle)

Answer (score 0):

Either could be correct depending on whether you are treating “X and Y” as a single item or as two items. The latter is far more common, but the former does happen, such as when a proper noun contains the word “and”.